# Error in bq load "Could not convert value to string"

Tags: google-bigquery, fluentd

I tried to load logs from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery by the bq command
and I've got this error "Could not convert value to string".

my example data

```
{"ids":"1234,5678"}
{"ids":1234}
```

my example schema

```
[
    { "name":"ids", "type":"string" }
]
```

It seems IDs can't convert by none quote at single ID.
Data is made with fluent-plugin-s3, but more than one ID connected by a comma can be bound up with a quotation and isn't made single id.

How can I load these data to BigQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to transform your data to include numbers like strings.

Comment: Is it better to make me transform how in this case?

Comment: Well check different fluentd plugins that can help you, maybe https://github.com/lob/fluent-plugin-json-transform

Comment: It seems fluent-plugin-typecast suits in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well check different fluentd plugins that can help you, maybe

- https://github.com/lob/fluent-plugin-json-transform
- https://github.com/tarom/fluent-plugin-typecast